# Regular expressing warning me no attribute called group

Tags: python, regex

I have a string called "sunday" that equals "1200-1700" and I am trying to retrieve the two numbers seperately. To do this I tried using the `re` module. `match = re.search(r'\W\d\d\d\d', sunday)` gives me `<re.Match object; span=(4, 9), match='-1700'><re.Match object; span=(4, 9), match='-1700'>`. When I try match.group() I get an error saying `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`. I just want to assign the '-1700' to a variable?

Comment: [Your code works](https://ideone.com/KYyIG7)

Answer (score 0):

you can try `re.search(r'(\W\d\d\d\d)', sunday)`

```
>>> re.search(r'(\W\d\d\d\d)', sunday).groups()[0]
>>>> '-1700'
```

Also,  if you change your regex with
`re.search(r'(\d{4})\W(\d{4})', sunday)` you'll grep both numbers at once

```
>>> re.search(r'(\d{4})\W(\d{4})', sunday).groups()
>>> ('1200', '1700')
```

Comment: I already tried that? "```match = re.search(r'\W\d\d\d\d', sunday)```"

Comment: @xdmojojojodx - you've to place the parentheses, around the stuff which you would like to capture

Comment: The problem is that I can't use .groups() because it says it's not an attribute

Comment: @xdmojojojodx - can you copy paste your exact code  in the  question

Comment: the only parts invloving regex are in my question apart from the ```import re``` at the very top of all my code

Comment: @xdmojojojodx - and how should we help you further, if you can't share exactly what you've done? Like wiktor Stribizew has said &  proven!, your question should work. Thus something else might be wrong,  but without any other information, we can't help.